# Unity3D: Animation Stutter

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

When I move my mouse slowly my animations stutter heavily. Here is what it looks like.

[Gif of Animation](https://gfycat.com/NeglectedUnrulyDogfish)

As you can see when moving the mouse quickly the animations preform exactly how I want them to. The problem is they dont when moving slowly. I would like some help on how to eliminate or reduce the stuttering.

Here is my setup:

```
void Update()
{
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    var y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");



    if(Time.time > nextActionTime)
    {
        nextActionTime += period;
        CheckIdle();
    }

    if (!paused && !sideScroller)
    {
        if (walking)
            Walk();


        //Animation detect if mouse has moved
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") > 0 && Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") == 0 && !running && !fire)
        {
            mouseMoved = true;
            rightR = true;
            //RotateRight();
            VisualBlendTree();
            Debug.Log("Moving Right, Bitch!");
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0 && Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") == 0 && !running && !fire)
        {
            mouseMoved = true;
            leftR = true;
            //RotateLeft();
            VisualBlendTree();
            Debug.Log("Moving Left, Bitch!");
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") > 0 && Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") == 0 && !running && !fire)
        {
            mouseMoved = true;
            upR = true;
            //RotateUp();
            VisualBlendTree();
            Debug.Log("Moving Up, Bitch!");
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") < 0 && Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") == 0 && !running && !fire)
        {
            mouseMoved = true;
            downR = true;
            //RotateDown();
            VisualBlendTree();
            Debug.Log("Moving Down, Bitch!");
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") == 0 && Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") == 0 && !running && !fire)
        {
            mouseMoved = false;
            leftR = false;
            rightR = false;
            upR = false;
            downR = false;
            Debug.Log("Moving Nowhere, Bitch!");

        }

        Move(x, y);

    }
}

void CheckIdle()
{
    if (!Input.GetKey("a") && !Input.GetKey("s") && !Input.GetKey("d") && !Input.GetKey("w") && !mouseMoved && !fire && !running)
        Idle();

    Debug.Log("Checkint Idle");
}


private void Move(float x, float y)
{
    animatorComponent.SetFloat("VelX", x);
    animatorComponent.SetFloat("VelY", y);
}


public void Idle()
{
    running = false;
    vibrating = false;
    leftR = false;
    rightR = false;
    upR = false;
    downR = false;

    animatorComponent.Play("CannonIdle");
    Debug.Log("Cannon Idle Called");

}
```

Animation and Blend Tree Setup:

[image: Base Layer]

[image: Blend Tree & Freeform Directional Setup]

Comment: How is your camera attached to this object?

Comment: It is a child of the camera. https://i.imgur.com/tiTxU7E.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is a little smoothing or interpolation. A really simple interpolation function within the Move function would be as follows.

```
private Vector2 lastMouseVel;
private void Move(float x, float y)
{
    Vector2 interpolated = (lastMouseVel + new Vector2(x, y)) /2;
    animatorComponent.SetFloat("VelX", interpolated.x);
    animatorComponent.SetFloat("VelY", interpolated.y);
    lastMouseVel = new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

Comment: This totally reduced the stutter! I love you!! Been trying to fix this for like 2 months and made 2 posts on the Unity Forums and had 0 people reply to it. I am coming here first next time.

Comment: Glad I could help!